# Session timeout on a asp.net with master pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages, session-timeout

I have an asp.net app with master pages. I need to have a session timeout after 10 minutes, for which I have a javascript code block. Is there any other more efficient way to do a session timeout rather than have a javascript code block on every page? (I am not using membership provider).

Comment: Did you try setting session timeout in web.config?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the timeout of your session in your web.config

```
<sessionState 
   mode="InProc" 
   stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424" 
   stateNetworkTimeout="10" 
   sqlConnectionString="data source=127.0.0.1;Integrated Security=SSPI" 
   sqlCommandTimeout="30" 
   customProvider="" 
   cookieless="UseCookies" 
   cookieName="ASP.NET_SessionId" 
   timeout="10" 
   allowCustomSqlDatabase="false" 
   regenerateExpiredSessionId="true" 
   partitionResolverType="" 
   useHostingIdentity="true">
   <providers>
      <clear />
   </providers>
</sessionState>
```

reference:[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9(vs.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9%28vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Using javascript is a bad idea, you can do what you want easily on the server.

Add this to your Global.asax

```
protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Session.Timeout = 10;
}
```

And this to your web.config

```
    <configuration>
    <system.web>
       <sessionState timeout="10"></sessionState>
    </system.web>
    </configuration>
```

**You need to add both to make it work effectively.**

Answer (score 2):

you can simply do this on server side. there is no point to time your session on client side. in that case, you can do it centrally on master page or webconfig or global.asax.

Answer (score 2):

You can made changes in web.config file by adding following to have session timeout:

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
          <forms timeout="10"/>
    </authentication>
    <sessionState timeout="10"  />
</system.web>
```

You can do it from c# by using following code:

```
Session.Timeout = 10;
```